# A coin is tossed $m+n$ times. Find the probability of getting atleast $m$ consecutive heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A coin is tossed $m+n$ times. Find the probability of getting atleast $m$ consecutive heads

I already know that the exact same question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456272/a-coin-is-tossed-mn-times-mn-show-that-the-probability-of-atleast-m-co)

But I am trying to solve it using another method.

1. The first case is when at least $m$ consecutive heads occur before getting a tail. That is
   $$HHH\cdots HH \_~\_~\_~\_~\cdots\_~\_$$
   Number of ways $=2^{n}$
2. Second case is when Tail comes first and then $m$ consecutive heads.
   Number of ways $=2^{n-1}$
3. Third case is:$$\_THHH\cdots HH\_~\_~\_\cdots\_~\_$$
   First position can either be $H$ or $T$.
   Number of ways $=(1/2)^{1}\cdot2^{n-2}$

There will be many cases. Last case is when $m$ consecutive heads come after $n$ trials. Number of ways is $2^{n-1}\cdot1/2^{0}$

Total number of ways $$=2^n+2^{n-1}+1/2^1\cdot2^{n-2}+1/2^2\cdot2^{n-3}+\cdots +2^{n-1}\cdot1/2^0$$
$$=2^n+(n+1)1/2^{n-1}$$

Probability is $$\frac{2^n+(n+1)1/2^{n-1}}{2^{m+n}}=\frac{n+2}{2^{m+1}}$$
This is the required answer 
By (S.A.M).B-tech-N.I.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^{m+n}$ outcomes in total. Now treat the string of $m$ consecutive heads as a single head with $n$ more tosses. So our string of $m$ heads can be in $n+1$ different positions relative to the other $n$ coin tosses. The outcomes of those $n$ tosses do not matter since your question asks for at least a string of $m$ heads. So the probability should be:
                        $(n+1)2^{n}/2^{n+m}$. Is this what you got?

Comment: What's the mistake in my approach?

Comment: I think the main mistake in your approach might be that you are forgeting to account for all the possible ways in which the string of m, m+1,m+2...heads can be. Note that for a string of m heads , treating it as a single block we can have it in n+1 different positions.

Comment: Is there any other constraint on m and n? Because I feel, we may count certain cases multiple times with this approach. Say m consecutive heads are marked as H other heads and tails as h and t respectively. so this approach will count ..hH.. and ..Hh.. twice, but these are essentially the same patterns. What am I missing here?

Comment: but the answer given by solver is wrong.